# How to make a Post Machine for $a^nb^n$?

Tags: context-free, automata

I have tried to make a Post machine for that all words of the form $a^nb^n$ by the following steps.

1. add a marker '#'
2. read first 'a'
3. read next 'a's and add them
4. read first 'b'
5. read next 'b's and add them
6. read '#' (that we added in the first step)

repeat steps while input tape is not empty

but this algorithm also accepts words of the form $(ab)^n$ e.g abab, ababab
I want to make a Post machine that only accepts words of the form $a^nb^n$
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.
One possible solution is checking the format of the input in the beginning of the procedure to get sure the user input is in form of $a^nb^n$. If it is in correct format then go to next step otherwise reject. In next step using the instructions that you've written can accept the language. But one thing which is important in post-turing machines is it's model (eg. Davis), which you didn't mention.

Answer (score 1):

This language $a^nb^n$ can be recognized by a [one counter automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_automaton),
i.e. a pushdown automaton with only one kind of stack symbol (other than the stack bottom).

That can be easily mimicked by a Post machine (with capital P, like
Turing), according to the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%E2%80%93Turing_machine#1936:_Post_model).

So first try to design the PDA with a single stack symbol (that is
easy), and then translate it to a Post machine.

But I am not sure you are using the same type of Post machine as described in Wikipedia, and you did not describe your model.

Answer (score 0):

Given the description of the steps in your Post machine, and assuming that step 6 connects to step 1, then you have the correct algorithm.

Your machine will accept only the language $a^n b^n$ and it will not accept $abab$ or any other word not of the form $a^n b^n$.

Given the example $abab$, the machine will crash/reject at step 5 after it reads the second $a$ in $abab$.